# Prioritising a row fetching by considering the column values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 columns like shown below and first column is the the primary key ,

```
Col1 Col2 Col3   Pk
---- ---- ------ --
 112 Liq  Tall    1
 112 asf  Small   2
 113 Asf  S1      3
 113 fgs  S2      4
 115 Mid  F1      5
```

Here I need to fletch the rows depending upon the value in column 2, without adding any new columns to it.

Like if "LIQ " is there then it gets a first priority. All other will have normal priority and we fletch those as first-come-first-serve.

We get output like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3   Pk
---- ---- ------ --
 112 Liq  Tall    1
 113 Asf  S1      3
 115 Mid  F1      5
```

Comment: Is this for Oracle or for MySQL? Also, what do you mean by "fletch"? Do you mean "fetch"? It looks like you're after picking 1 row per each distinct col1 - you mention it depends on the value of col2, but the logic you mention ("LIQ" = highest priority) doesn't explain why you get the pk = 3 and 5 rows returned. What's the actual logic, please? (My gut feeling is that you want to investigate the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function to assign row numbers for each group, and then filter the set where the row number is 1.)

Comment: Oracle and yes one district row  ... if "LIQ" is their then only give priority other wise no priority... and fletch the first town on basis of col2 pointing column 3 and it doesn't depend on row_number I think ... but still I don't know

Comment: and how do we know what the "first one" is, based on col2? Is it alphabetical?

Comment: Someone said to use decode or something like that

Comment: we just have to check whether liq is their or not ..

Comment: If their then fletch the complete row ... if not their then just fletch the first entry which is their in column 1

Comment: What I mean is, there is no inherent order to an ordinary heap table. So when you say "get the first row", you need to say how the rows need to be ordered. In other words, in your expected output why do you pick the row with `col2 = Asf` for `col1 = 113`, rather than the row with `col2 = fgs`. Unless, of course, you don't care and we should just pick any row?

Comment: Like we need one entry depending on col1 and col2 and again we have to give priority depending on value .. if liq is their then only have it other wise just get the first come first basis

Comment: What defines "first come, first serve" for your data? Would it be ok to return the rows with pk = 1, 4, and 5, for example? Ie. one row per col1 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 112 col1, 'Liq' col2, 'Tall' col3, 1 pk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 112 col1, 'asf' col2, 'Small' col3, 2 pk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 113 col1, 'Asf' col2, 'S1' col3, 3 pk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 113 col1, 'fgs' col2, 'S2' col3, 4 pk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 115 col1, 'Mid' col2, 'F1' col3, 5 pk FROM dual)
-- end of data setup; see SQL below
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       pk
FROM   (SELECT col1,
               col2,
               col3,
               pk,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY CASE WHEN UPPER(col2) = 'LIQ' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, col2 ASC) rn
        FROM   your_table)
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER BY col1;

      COL1 COL2 COL3          PK
---------- ---- ----- ----------
       112 Liq  Tall           1
       113 Asf  S1             3
       115 Mid  F1             5
```

This works by assigning each row a row number across each col1 value, and ordering it first* by checking if the uppercase value of col2 is "LIQ" and giving that the lowest number (in my example, 1) and everything else a higher number (in my example, 2)\ and then ordering by col2 ascending.

If you need a different ordering of the rows, you would need to amend the second part of the ORDER BY statement in the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function.

Finally, once the rows have been labelled with a row number, you can then filter them by selecting the rows labelled with "1".

*It's at this point that you could use Neville's solution instead of hardcoding the priority values - i.e. have a separate table that contains the priority values, and join that to your table and use the priority value to order by first in the ROW_NUMBER() function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a SQL database to test this right now, but the way I usually solve this is to create a "prioritization" table.

```
priority_term     priority_weighting
-------------------------------------
Liq                               10
```

You can then use an outer join, and order by priority_weighting, something like:

```
select Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3,
       Pk, 
       isnull(priority_weigthing, -1)
from my_table mt
outer join prioritization p
  on mt.col2 = p.priority_term
order by p.priority_weighting desc
```